# mysqld-5.0.41-community-nt Server does not support 4-byte encoded UTF8 characters

Tags: c#, mysql

I have tried the c# application in different server MySQL.

This application bind the **GridView** with **DataSet** and **DataTable**.

On the version **5.1.51-community** of MySQL I don't have problem , but in version **5.0.41-community-nt** I have this error :

```
ERROR [HY000] [MySQL][ODBC 5.2(w) Driver][mysqld-5.0.41-community-nt]
Server does not support 4-byte encoded UTF8 characters.
```

I have tried with this suggestion on Google without success:
[MySQL ODBC 5.1 Set Names not allowed by driver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6361744/mysql-odbc-5-1-set-names-not-allowed-by-driver)

I'm not an administrator of MySQL Server version **5.0.41-community-nt**, how to do resolve this ?

Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: v5.0.41 is about ten years old. You should use a slightly more recent version, don't you think so?

Comment: @Shadow thank you for reply but I don't an administrator of MySQL Server and I can't update this version, I'm sorry.

Comment: Then you are stuck and you need to explain this whomever came up with the requirements.